# how to stop asyncTask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my android project I use many `AsynTask` in one activity. I need to stop one `AsynTask` when I start other.

I'm using `myAsynTask.cancel(true);` in my android project. But it does stop the `AsynTask`.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", args[0]);

        Log.d("get value: ", params.toString());

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_comment, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All matches: ", json.toString());

        if(isCancelled()) {
            finish();
        }
        else {

            try {

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                    JSONmatches = json.getJSONArray(TAG_vedio);

                    for (int i = 0; i < JSONmatches.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = JSONmatches.getJSONObject(i);

                        String title = c.getString(TAG_title);
                        String url = c.getString(TAG_url);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_title, title);
                        map.put(TAG_url, url);

                        arrayList22.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: In this case, you should use a library for webservice requests. For example retrofit is the best choice for this job. the link of it : http://square.github.io/retrofit/. It arranges and supports multi requests.

Answer (score 1):

You actively have to check for `isCancelled` while executing your loop in `doInBackground`.

You should `break` the loop if `isCanceled` is true.

Answer (score 1):

**From the official [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):**

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean)`.
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` to
>   return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of `onPostExecute(Object)` will be invoked after
>   `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])`, if
>   possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: it is invoke **isCancelled()** first but it also invoke  **onPostExecute(Object)** after **isCancelled()** runs.

Comment: check the the `isCancelled()` value and if it is false then continue your work in `postExecute()`

Comment: `if (isCancelled()) {
                this.cancel(true);
            }
            else{
               
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          
          
           

            } `